# InAppBrowser sometimes empty/blank

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, inappbrowser, ionic3

I'm working on a project where I make much use of the `InAppBrowser` to view different documents (PDF, DOC, DOCX). I do this with the help och `docs.google.com`, and the documents are stored in `firebase-storage`.
Most of the time it works great on my Android device! But sometimes all I get is an empty white screen, and I have to press the back button to close the `InAppBrowser` and then re-open it to show the document.

When remotely debugging this strange behavior in Chrome developer tools I see that the `loadstart` and `loadstop` events are called appropriately:

[image: Chrome developer tools, when remotely debugging the app, while opening InAppBrowser]

When i look at the `HTML` in the empty/white `InAppBrowser` i see empty `<body>`-tags:

[image: Chrome developer tools, looking at the HTML for the empty white InAppBrowser]

The code im using to open the `InAppBrowser`:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { InAppBrowser, InAppBrowserObject } from '@ionic-native/in-app-browser';
import { ScreenOrientation } from '@ionic-native/screen-orientation';
import { LoaderService } from './loader-service';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

@Injectable()
export class FirebaseStorageService{
    browserOptions: string;
    browser: InAppBrowserObject;

    constructor(
        private iab: InAppBrowser,
        private loaderService:LoaderService,
        private platform: Platform,
        private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation
    ){
        this.browserOptions = 'zoom=no,location=no,useWideViewPort=no,hidden=yes,enableViewportScale=yes';
    }

    viewPdf(path: string, loadText?:string):Promise<any>{
        this.showLoader(loadText);
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase.storage().ref().child(path).getDownloadURL().then(url => {
                let newURL = 'https://docs.google.com/gview?&url=' + encodeURIComponent(url);
                this.startBrowser(newURL);
                resolve();
            })
            .catch(err => {
                if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
                    this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
                }
                reject(err);
            });
        })
    }

    private startBrowser(path:string):void{
        this.browser = this.iab.create(path, '_blank', this.browserOptions);
        if(this.platform.is('cordova')){
            this.handleBrowserSubscriptions();
            this.screenOrientation.unlock();
        }
    }

    private handleBrowserSubscriptions():void{
        let stopSub = this.browser.on('loadstop').subscribe(event => {
            console.log('loadstop', event)
            this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
            this.browser.show();
            stopSub.unsubscribe();
            errorSub.unsubscribe();
        });

        let exitSub = this.browser.on('exit').subscribe(event => {
            console.log('exit:',event)
            this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
            exitSub.unsubscribe();
            this.browser.close();
            this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);
        });

        let errorSub = this.browser.on('loaderror').subscribe(event => {
            console.log('loaderror', event)
            this.loaderService.dismissLoader();
            this.browser.close();
            this.screenOrientation.lock(this.screenOrientation.ORIENTATIONS.PORTRAIT);
            stopSub.unsubscribe();
            errorSub.unsubscribe();
        });

        let startSub = this.browser.on('loadstart').subscribe(event => {
            console.log('loadstart', event);
        })
    }
}
```

Ionic info:

`Cordova CLI: 7.0.1
Ionic Framework Version: 3.2.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.0
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.9.4
Xcode version: Not installed`

Has anyone else experienced this, or does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: is your `loaderror` firing ? at the time of blank screen?

Comment: No it's not firing.

Comment: Did you try running your project using AndroidStudio to check if the InAppBrowser plugin logs something useful on the native part of the app?

Comment: No, I can definitely try that!

Comment: How do I do that exactly? :)

Comment: Open AndroidStudio, choose `File > Open...` and navigate to your `platforms` folder, choose the `android` folder and click `OK`. You may have to confirm a few dialogs or update a few things before you can run the project.

Answer (score 0):

you are using one of the way to open the doc's in Android's web view

**Solution-1:**
your current webview  you can modifiy like below:

```
encodeURI('https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.your-server.com/files/your_file.pdf')
```

encode complete url including `https://docs.google.com`

here is another way to load the url:

http://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://example.com/example.pdf

if any of this solutions doesn't works out , then try to download the file and open it in browser.

Answer (score -1):

first step => install streaming-Media plugins => https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/streaming-media

second step => let url = 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=' + YOUR_URL;

just Add this => 'https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url='
work in InAppBrowser.
this is work for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).